# How to convert camel case to proper case in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, regex, vue.js, vuejs2, ag-grid

I am retrieving data from MongoDB collection & filling the data in ag-grid. I want the column header to be in proper case with Spacing. Initially, the collection has text line 'businessAreaName' and I want it to look like 'Business Area Name'.

I am using the concept of regular expression but not able to figure out expression for proper case.

```
headerName: x.replace(/_/g, ' ').replace(/\w\S*/g, function (txt) 
  { 
    return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase(); 
  })
```

The expression above is giving me output as 'Businessareaname'. Any kind of suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Something like this ? `"businessAreaName".replace(/([A-Z])/g, ' $1').replace(/^./, Function.call.bind("".toUpperCase))`

Comment: @blex so $1 is the logic to read the space in the expression?

Comment: In the `/([A-Z])/g` regex, you can see parentheses. These parentheses create a _capturing group_. It captures every capital letter, and replaces it with a space and the letter, which is represented with `$1`. If the expression had multiple sets of parentheses, they could be accessed with `$1`, `$2`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you really need to do is

1. replace every uppercase character with a space, followed by that character
2. replace the first character with uppercase

This can be done like so:

```
const deCamelCase = str => str.replace(/[A-Z]/g, ' $&').replace(/^./, toUppercase);
const toUppercase = str => str.toUpperCase();
```

Breaking this down:

```
str => str.replace(/[A-Z]/g, ' $&')
```

This matches any uppercase character (latin alphabet only!) and replaces it with a string consisting of a space, plus the whole matched string, coded as `$&`. Note that we need to use the `/g` flag to make sure we match every instance.

```
str => str.replace(/^./, toUppercase)
```

This matches the first character in the string only, and replaces it using the `toUppercase` function, which I define on a separate line for readability.

Comment: No problem. Good luck with your project!